# Writing controls like a button in C++\Win32 (not MFC or CLI)?

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

I have several questions concerning the controls like a button, if You could answer i would be very much pleased.

Questions:

1. Is there any way to create a control like a button, but not-standard, i mean, not that strict-rectangled button
2. How do I handle mouse hover events within the control

Regards,
Galymzhan Sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's relatively easy. If you want the same behaviour as a button (click, hover etc etc), then the best bet is to subclass the button control.

Have a read of the following MSDN articles:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773183.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997565.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633569.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This one is tricky one.
I developed my own GUI, it is advance topic.
Here is how i developed mine.

1. Create class called button

   - In button class, create all
     variables needed like the width and
     Height of the button
   - Have a render function
   - If you gonna let users load their own
     texture for the button, you should
     include a load function
2. Create class for wrapper

   - Have a Add button function and use ids for buttons
   - Have a EventProc  that checks for hovers, clicks...
   - Have a Render controls function to render all buttons

This is just simple way to write buttons